# How can two eclipse plugin use the same preferences store?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, preferences, eclipse-pde

I have two plugins, say com.site.plugin.core and com.site.plugin.ui.
I'd like to separate core part from UI part, so at plugin com.site.plugin.ui I created Preferences page where I defined some preferences, which should be used by com.site.plugin.core. I check article at [Eclipse site](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Preferences/preferences.htm), but it is quite outdated, and linked bug also do not provide much info.
So is it possible to do this using standard Eclipse mechanism, or I need use direct low-level API via package org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that the UI depends on Core and not otherwise. In this case, you could use the Core's preference store in the UI plugin's preference page, like this:

```Java
IPreferenceStore store = CorePluginActivator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore();
setPreferenceStore(store);
```

In this way the preference page will store the values in the Core plugin. The Core plugin can use the values without depending on the UI plugin.

Answer (score 3):

You can also access preferences in other plug-ins using the preference service:

```java
String pref = Platform.getPreferencesService().getString(
    "org.myplugin.preferences.page", "pref name",
    "default value if pref not found", null);
```

Comment: Note that for me the 'org.myplugin.preferences.page' did not work, I had to use 'org.myplugin.id'.

Comment: For me it was also the ID, thanks for the hint. Like this, this is the perfect solution for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Prefs stores are found per plugin. This is one way to get a prefs store for
the plugin whose activator class is ActivatorA.

```
IPreferenceStore store = ActivatorA.getDefault().getPreferenceStore();
```

If you want another plugin to refer to the same store, perhaps you could
expose some api on ActivatorA for it to get there, e.g.

```
public IPreferenceStore getSharedPrefs() {
    return ActivatorA.getDefault().getPreferenceStore();
}
```

The second plugin would find the shared store by doing this

```
IPreferenceStore sharedPrefs = ActivatorA.getSharedPrefs();
```

Good luck.

Comment: Hmmm... But in this case my core plugin should know about UI part. It is not good.

Comment: OK. In general terms what would an acceptable way for the core plug-in to locate the shared data, if not via the plugin that creates it. How about: a filepath?, Dialog-settings? a URL?